# How to read array field from database using c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, postgresql, npgsql

I am using C# with postgresql. In the database I have a table named `test` and in this table I have a column named `arr` that it's datatype is `double[]` and I stored multiple record like this `{1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 1, 4}`. Now, how to return those records into C# program and stored in a list for example `List<double[]> arr1 = new List<double[]>();`

Who can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading an array column in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654994/reading-an-array-column-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You should add your code then we can help you, because there are a dozen of ways to do this, e.g. using Linq, running query statements directly, getting data from a service provider, etc.

Answer (score 6):

For array datatypes, all you have to do is cast the result as an array of double:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();

NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select arr from test", conn);
NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    double[] myArray = (double[])reader.GetValue(0);
    // do your bidding
}

reader.Close();
```

-- EDIT 2/18/2021 --

As of Npgsql 5.0, the above method seems to work most of the time, but the documents specify a different way to extract array datatypes:

```
double[] myArray = reader.GetFieldValue<double[]>(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a walkthrough, Using PostgreSQL in your C# (.NET): [Using PostgreSQL in your C# (.NET)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30989/Using-PostgreSQL-in-your-C-NET-application-An-intr)

You will need to give us some specific problems that you are having so we can help solve the problem.

Comment: I am using this idea

          `List<double[]> arr1 = new List<double[]>();

            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["test"].Rows)
            {   
                arr1.Add(row["arr"].Select(s => Double.Parse(s)).ToList());
            }`


but, I got error!!

Comment: Error 2 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,TResult>>)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context C:\Users\PCLORD\Desktop\ShowImg\ShowImg\Default.aspx.cs 103 39 ShowImg