# Storing result convert.FromBase64String into postgres bytea

Tags: c#, arrays, postgresql, byte, bytea

I have a mini system where frontend will pass the file in base64 format to the backend. I used convert.frombase64string in order for me to convert the base64 format into byte array and used file stream to save the file into the server.

The codes are shown as below:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(file.Split(',')[1]);

using (var file = new FileStream("D:test.txt", FileMode.Create))
{
    file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    file.Flush();
}

var db = await _context.insertDB.FromSql("INSERT INTO blobTable (blob) VALUES ('" + bytes + "')").SingleAsync();
```

And this is the result that I select from blobTable.

[image]

As the return result from Convert.FromBase64String() is byte array. So that I decided to store this value into my database which is postgres with column bytea[].

The problem is that is it so weird that when I trying to

```
console.writeline(bytes);
```

The result is printed as "system.byte[]" instead of the bytes value. So that "system.byte[]" is stored into my database instead of the actual value.

Can anybody tell me how do I store the return value from convert.frombase64string() into postgres bytea[] column? Thanks you.

Comment: The problem is in your code that is writing to postgres, but you haven't showed us that code. It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: `" + bytes + "` **is** converting it into a `string` - even if you don't want it to. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/7160845/34092 for how to pass byte arrays correctly.

Comment: You should use paramterized SQL queries - it would solve your problem.